# jQuery.each() in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, foreach

I have to loop in a JSON array to get some informations in `node`, but I only know how to to this using `$.each()` in jQuery. So I want to know if there are any alternative for the `$.each` jQuery function in node.js?

Comment: *"...but I only know how to to this using `$.each()` in jQuery"* That makes me a little sad. You should learn the language. If it's an Array, the closest alternative is `.forEach()`.

Comment: Yeah, a year on pure jQuery and starting on node.js makes this things happen.

Comment: By the way, I suggest you take a look at [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) – it's available as a node module, extremely lightweight and provides a myriad of convenience methods such as `each()`, `map()`, `reduce()`, etc.

Comment: @squint, `.forEach()` is available only for Array instances, but the person asking wants to iterate over Object with alphabetical keys.

Comment: @MaxTsepkov: I guess I don't see any evidence of that in the question. He says it's an array. But if it was a non-Array object, the point remains since I would hope `for-in` would be among the first things learned.

Comment: @squint, you're right

Comment: @vzwick, [lodash](http://lodash.com/) is more advanced drop-in replacement for underscore.js

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this

```
for (var name in myobject) {
   console.log(name + ": " + myobject[name]);
}
```

Where `myobject` could be your JSON data

Check out the answer here: [Looping through JSON with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829007/looping-through-json-with-node-js)

Comment: This will also loop over the properties stored in `Object`'s prototype. Always check that by `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @HieuVanMach - So *please!* add that to your answer.

Answer (score 15):

You should use the native `for ( key in obj )` iteration method:

```
for ( var key in yourJSONObject ) {
    if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(yourJSONObject, key) ) {
        // do something
        // `key` is obviously the key
        // `yourJSONObject[key]` will give you the value
    }
}
```

---

If you're dealing with an array, just use a regular `for` loop:

```
for ( var i = 0, l = yourArray.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    // do something
    // `i` will contain the index
    // `yourArray[i]` will have the value
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the array's native `forEach` method, [which is a tad slower](http://www.symphonious.net/2010/10/09/javascript-performance-for-vs-foreach/), but more concise:

```
yourArray.forEach(function (value, index) {
    // Do something
    // Use the arguments supplied. I don't think they need any explanation...
});
```

Comment: If you make heavy use of callbacks (and you probably do in nodejs) you may have no choice but to use the forEach method. For example if you make async calls inside the loop and you have to print the outcome of each element in the array, array[i] wouldn't work inside the inner callback.

Comment: @Joseph Silber,  your answer is the correct one, but regarding forEach, the people that might be looking at this will probably need to also know about Object.keys if they are working with an object.

Answer (score 4):

In nodejs I found `Array.forEach(callback)` to best suite my needs. It works just like jQuery:

```
myItems.forEach(function(item) {
   console.log(item.id);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is just javascript, you can do the loop yourself.

I don't know the structure of the JSON array you're looping but you can use a [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) method to get every property of an object.

So you would do something like:

```
    for( var i = 0; len = jsonArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        for(var prop in jsonArray[i]) {
         //do something with jsonArray[i][prop], you can filter the prototype properties with hasOwnProperty
        }
}
```

Also you can use the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method that `Array` provides, that works in a similar way that jQuerys `.each()`

good luck!