# how to use ForEach loop in nested format

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I am a newbie in Node.js and still learning the basic syntax

I was wondering if we want to use two different JSON object and then compare their values before giving the output then how do we use `forEach` in a nested manner like normal `for`?

```
var count = 0;
app.locals.author.forEach(function(item)
{
    app.locals.post.forEach(function(item1){

        if(item.id == item1.userId)
        {
            count++;
        }
    });
    res.send('Author = ' + item.name + " No of Posts done = " + count+"\n");
    count = 0;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "one result"? Only one author, only one post? What's it supposed to look like? Also, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829007/looping-through-json-with-node-js .

Comment: one result means to get a single output that will contain the fields from both the JSON objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're just after a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
item.posts = app.locals.post.filter(x => x.userId === item.id)
```